# Is there a Java library of Unix functions?

Tags: java, unix, java-native-interface, posix

I am looking for a Java library to interface with standard Unix functions, i.e. `stat()`, `getpwuid()`, `readlink()`.

This used to exist, and was called `javaunix`.  It was released back in 2000.  See this [announcement](http://lwn.net/2000/1019/a/javaunix.php3).  But the project page is now gone.

Is there any modern replacement for these types of functions in Java today?  One could make a system call to `/bin/ls -l` and parse the output, or write a custom JNI method, but these approaches are more work than simply using the old `javaunix` library.

**Clarification --** In order to find out a file's owner, from a C program, it should call `stat()` which gives the UID of the owner, and then use `getpwuid()` to get the account's name from the UID.  In Java this can be done through a custom JNI method, or the `javaunix` library which uses JNI.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm aware of two compelling projects:

- [posix for Java](http://bmsi.com/java/posix/) (based on JNI) [derived from Jython]
- [jna-posix](http://kenai.com/projects/jna-posix) (based on JNA) [derived from JRuby]

Personally I like very much [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/). Take a look at this example of mine, mapping `link(2)`:

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

class Link {

    private static final C c =
        (C) Native.loadLibrary("c", C.class);

    private static interface C extends Library {

        /** see man 2 link */
        public int link(String oldpath, String newpath);
    }

    @Override
    protected void hardLink(String from, String to) {
        c.link(to, from);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

JNA-POSIX is stagnant currently, as far as I know.

The developers went on to create [JNR-POSIX](https://github.com/jnr/jnr-posix)

Answer (score -3):

I would be surprised to see one, considering it would almost necessarily be platform-specific. Java is not the best tool for that job. But you could certainly hook in via JNI or calls out to external programs if you insist. Or perhaps look into Groovy, which I understand is reasonably good for shell scripting, though I have no personal experience with it.

Answer (score -4):

I don't know any library with the Unix functions.

for most of the functions, I believe, you can use the standard Java API to do what you want. for example, there's no need to use the command `ls` to read the files of some directory. but in some specific cases, like `stat` (to find out if a file is a link) you have to use JNI.