# JNA causes UnsatisfiedLinkException with Unix Stat

Tags: java, c, linux, java-native-interface, jna

So, I'm attempting to call the Linux C - stat function.

My JNA code:

```
    public int stat(bap path, bap statdump);
```

the bap class:

```
public static class bap extends Structure {

    public byte[] array;

    public bap(int size) {
        array = new byte[size];
    }

    @Override
    protected List getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList(new String[]{"array"});
    }

}
```

Which, while nasty, performs as a byte array pointer for many other functions successfully.
What I think the problem is, is here: `int stat(const char *restrict path, struct stat *restrict buf);`, as defined by http://linux.die.net/man/3/stat

How do I pass a constant char array, and what does the *restrict mean? I attempted to google, but I don't think it liked * in the search query, as nothing was relevant.

EDIT: full exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:      43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'stat': java: undefined       symbol: stat
    at com.sun.jna.Function.<init>(Function.java:208)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:536)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:513)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:499)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:199)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.stat(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: [`restrict`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict) is a hint to the C compiler, so you can ignore it for purposes of JNA function mappings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [`sys/stat.h`](http://linux.die.net/include/sys/stat.h) to see if there's an actual declaration for `stat()` or if it's a C preprocessor macro?

In the link above, `stat` will actually be `stat64` if `__USE_FILE_OFFSET64` is defined.

To see if this is your problem, simply change the function name from `stat` to `stat64`.

As a more permanent solution supply a [function mapper](http://twall.github.io/jna/4.1.0/com/sun/jna/FunctionMapper.html) to your library load.

The following example first looks up the base label, then tries again after appending "64":

```
FunctionMapper mapper = new FunctionMapper() {
    public String getFunctionName(NativeLibrary library, java.lang.reflect.Method method) {
        String name = method.getName();
        try {
            library.getFunction(name);
        } catch(UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
            try {
                library.getFunction(name + "64");
                return name + "64";
            } catch(UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
                 // If neither variant worked, report failure on the base label
            }
        }
        return name;
    }
};
Map options = new HashMap() {
    { put(Library.OPTION_FUNCTION_MAPPER, mapper); }
};
library = Native.loadLibrary("c", options);
```

Comment: It actually turned out to be __xstat64, but you we're heading there, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible that `stat` function just don't exists on your installed libc version, as it happened to me.

`stat` function is not present on **Debian 11.6**  using `GLIBC 2.31` but it is at **Ubuntu 22.04** which is using `GLIBC 2.35`.

`libc stat` function is just a wrapper to `syscall` `4` though, so you can use the following code to call `stat` using `syscall` function

```
public interface Libc extends Library {

  Stats INSTANCE = Native.loadLibrary(Platform.C_LIBRARY_NAME, Libc.class);

  default int stat0(String pathname, Stat statbuf){
    return this.syscall(4, pathname, statbuf);
  }

  int syscall(int number, Object... args);

}
```

Complete code is [hosted here](https://github.com/mageddo/java-native-examples/blob/8da6244382b739f604450407c2d3e1674e8edb4f/src/main/java/nativeapi/jna/stat/Stats.java), if you're interested

**Debug**

Debian 11.6

```
$ strings /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6  | grep 'GNU C Library'
GNU C Library (Debian GLIBC 2.31-13+deb11u5) stable release version 2.31.

$ nm -D /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6  | grep ' stat'
00000000000ec1c0 W statfs@@GLIBC_2.2.5
00000000000ec1c0 W statfs64@@GLIBC_2.2.5
00000000000ec220 W statvfs@@GLIBC_2.2.5
00000000000ec220 W statvfs64@@GLIBC_2.2.5
00000000000ec040 T statx@@GLIBC_2.28
```

Ubuntu 22.02

```
$ strings /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6  | grep 'GNU C Library'
GNU C Library (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.35-0ubuntu3.1) stable release version 2.35.


$ nm -D /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6  | grep ' stat'
0000000000113e60 W stat@@GLIBC_2.33
0000000000113e60 W stat64@@GLIBC_2.33
00000000001142b0 W statfs@@GLIBC_2.2.5
00000000001142b0 W statfs64@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000114310 W statvfs@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000114310 W statvfs64@@GLIBC_2.2.5
00000000001141e0 T statx@@GLIBC_2.28
```