# Java Posix IPC Is there an API?

Tags: java, unix, ipc

I'm wondering if I can access to a Posix Message Queue in Java as I have an application that can't be modified and uses a message queue to talk to other processes.
Is there any api or package that do that?
I know that I can use JNI but I need to do this ASAP so no time to develop that.

Regards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a Java library of Unix functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088113/is-there-a-java-library-of-unix-functions)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A bit of Googling found [Posix for Java](http://www.bmsi.com/java/posix/).

Comment: yep, thanks i was looking that a few minutes ago, i will see if this helps, thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/) at **GitHub** (latest [`JavaDoc`](http://twall.github.io/jna/4.1.0/)).  Quoting the project's description:

> JNA provides Java programs easy access
>   to native shared libraries (DLLs on
>   Windows) without writing anything but
>   Java code—no JNI or native code is
>   required. This functionality is
>   comparable to Windows' Platform/Invoke
>   and Python's ctypes. Access is dynamic
>   at runtime without code generation.

[Several projects](https://github.com/twall/jna/#projects) are using it, including `IntelliJ IDEA`, `Cassandra`, and `Netbeans`.