# setsockopt in Java programs

Tags: java

From version 8 onwards FreeBSD supports IP_BINDANY socket option which the man page defines as:

> If the IP_BINDANY option is enabled on a SOCK_STREAM, SOCK_DGRAM or a
>     SOCK_RAW socket, one can bind(2) to any address, even one not bound to
>     any available network interface in the system.  This functionality (in
>     conjunction with special firewall rules) can be used for implementing a
>     transparent proxy.  The PRIV_NETINET_BINDANY privilege is needed to set
>     this option.

Is it possible to write a Java program that can use this functionality? I have checked the docs of [SocketOptions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/SocketOptions.html) and it obviously does not list this option. So is there any workaround?

with regards,

raj

Comment: I can't think of anything short of wrapping C++ via RMI. It'd be totally implementation dependant. Do you know that you really NEED bind-any, or is it just a "nice-to-have"?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Java was designed with portability in mind and `IP_BINDANY` is FreeBSD-specific. You can try passing [`24`](http://people.freebsd.org/~pjd/patches/bindany.patch) to `setOption()`, but it will fail on other platforms.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I will try to send 24 to setOption() and check that. This feature is a must have, so if this is too difficult in Java I might go with Perl, and yes portability is not an issue. This needs to run only in FreeBSD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to write a Java program that can use this functionality?

It is not possible using a pure Java.

> So is there any workaround?

There are a couple of JNA/JNI based libraries for making Posix system calls from a Java program; see this SO question/answer for details:

- [Is there a Java library of Unix functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088113/is-there-a-java-library-of-unix-functions/1088183#1088183)

I don't know if these are available for Java on FreeBSD.

---

On further thought, it might be possible to implement this in pure (though necessarily non-portable) Java.  It would entail creating subclasses of SocketImpl and/or DatagramSocketImpl and the necessary infrastructure to use them.  It would be complicated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Any case this program is supposed to run only on FreeBSD so portability is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a library in JNA to do the `setsockopt` bit reasonably portably. You can find it [here](https://github.com/abligh/jnasockopt).

However, to change the `bind` behaviour you may need to dig further into the socket code. For why, see [here](https://grahamedgecombe.com/blog/linux-tproxy-server-in-java), specifically this bit:

> So we just need to create a new `java.net.Socket` object, call `setsockopt()` and finally call `bind()` on the socket - easy, right? Unfortunately, it’s not quite so simple - creating a new Socket object in Java (in OpenJDK and the Oracle JVM) does not actually allocate a file descriptor. Instead, the file descriptor is allocated within Java’s `bind()` function itself - making it rather difficult to call `setsockopt()` at the appropriate point.

The author presents a reasonably complex workaround - I'm not going to copy his entire article here though.