# How can I check if a file is a Unix socket using Scala?

Tags: scala, sockets

I can create a socket locally using:

```
$ python -c "import socket as s; sock = s.socket(s.AF_UNIX); sock.bind('/mnt/somesocket')"
```

I can check that the file is a socket at the command-line via the following:

```
$ test foo.txt
$ echo $?
1
$ test -S somesocket
$ echo $?
0
```

How can I check if the file is a socket using Scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple options available, but none is perfect...

`test` will call `S_ISSOCK` macro as you can see from the [code here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/test.c):

```
struct stat stat_buf;
...
S_ISSOCK (stat_buf.st_mode)
```

The macro itself is very simple - just checks if certain bits are set via bitmasks. Relevant code from [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/linux/stat.h#L25):

```
#define S_IFMT  00170000
...
#define S_IFSOCK 0140000
...
#define S_ISSOCK(m)     (((m) & S_IFMT) == S_IFSOCK)
```

Thus if you would have a `stat` [structure](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html) with `st_mode` value you would be all set. However, that part is tricky.

Java NIO provides some POSIX support with [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) and [BasicFileAttributes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html#isOther()) classes. But it does not expose file mode or any test methods for sockets.
If you don't use various types of files you might be ok using `isOther`:

> boolean isOther()
>
> Tells whether the file is something other than a regular file,
>   directory, or symbolic link.

Otherwise you can try JNI / JNA implementations:

https://github.com/SerCeMan/jnr-fuse/blob/master/src/main/java/ru/serce/jnrfuse/struct/FileStat.java

[Is there a Java library of Unix functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088113/is-there-a-java-library-of-unix-functions)

Finally, the simplest but slowest solution is to call a process (shell) from Scala.