# Creation time of a file in java

Tags: java, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to discover a File's creation time with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586/how-to-discover-a-files-creation-time-with-java)

Using the java.io.File class to open a file, I am able to get the last modified date with lastModified().  Is there a way to find the creation time of the file?

Comment: The file-systems on certain operating systems don't support creation time.  For example, many unix file-systems don't have a creation time value which may be why Java doesn't have a File.created().

Answer (score 0):

[How to discover a File's creation time with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586/how-to-discover-a-files-creation-time-with-java)