# Convert 64 bit windows number to time Java

Tags: java, windows, time, bit

If I wanted to convert a 64 bit number that reprasents time in Windows using Java how would I do this?

The number is 129407978957060010

I'm just very confused as to how I would get this to work. Maths was never my thing :)

Many thanks

Comment: You need to clarify what the 64-bit number represents:  second, milliseconds?  Since what time?

Comment: Check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199478/java-display-windows-utc-time/5199640#5199640

Comment: It is a Windows time in milliseconds since Windows UTC started, there does not seem to be a way to convert it?!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That time is probably representing 100 nanosecond units since [Jan 1. 1601](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724284(v=vs.85).aspx). There's 116444736000000000 100ns between 1601 and 1970.

```
Date date = new Date((129407978957060010-116444736000000000)/10000);
```

Comment: I think you may have done it, it's so simple when you look at what you have done but so mind messing! I don't know anything about the date system in Windows. Thank you so much NOS I really do appericiate it! :)

Comment: You can calculate # of days between the years as: (369*365+(369/4)*1-3). Basically, 365 days per year, plus one day per four years for leap year, minus a day per century b/c there's no leap year in the years 1700, 1800, or 1900. From there, the 100ns ticks work out as answered here.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the 64-bit value is a [`FILETIME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) value, it represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601. The Java `Date` class stores the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970. To convert from the former to the latter, you can do this:

```
long windowsTime = 129407978957060010; // or whatever time you have

long javaTime = windowsTime / 10000    // convert 100-nanosecond intervals to milliseconds
                - 11644473600000;      // offset milliseconds from Jan 1, 1601 to Jan 1, 1970

Date date = new Date(javaTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

Java uses [Unix Timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). You can use an [online converter](http://www.epochconverter.com/) to see your local time.

To use it in java:

```
Date date = new Date(timestamp);
```

**Update:**

It seem that on  Windows they have [different time offset](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/167296). So on Windows machine you'd use this calculation to convert to Unix Timestamp:

```
#include <winbase.h>
#include <winnt.h>
#include <time.h>

void UnixTimeToFileTime(time_t t, LPFILETIME pft)
{
  // Note that LONGLONG is a 64-bit value
  LONGLONG ll;

  ll = Int32x32To64(t, 10000000) + 116444736000000000;
  pft->dwLowDateTime = (DWORD)ll;
  pft->dwHighDateTime = ll >> 32;
}
```

Comment: Just realized that on Windows they are (probably) using different timestamp offsets.

Comment: Your Java code is confusing me!

Answer (score 0):

public static void main(String as[]){

```
     String windowNTTimeStr = "131007981071882420";
     String finalDate = "";
    try {
//Windows NT time is specified as the number of 100 nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601.
//UNIX time is specified as the number of seconds since January 1, 1970. There are 134,774 days (or 11,644,473,600 seconds) between these dates.
//NT to Unix : Divide by 10,000,000 and subtract 11,644,473,600.
//Unix to NT : Add 11,644,473,600 and multiply by 10,000,000

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            Long windowsTime = Long.parseLong(windowNTTimeStr);
            long javaTime = windowsTime / 10000 - 11644473600000L;
            Date date = new Date(javaTime);
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.setTime(new Date(javaTime));

            Calendar cCurrent = Calendar.getInstance();
            cCurrent.setTime(new Date());
            cCurrent.add(Calendar.YEAR, 100);

            if (!(c.getTime().getYear() > cCurrent.getTime().getYear())) {
                finalDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            finalDate = null;
        }
        System.out.println(" Final Date is "+finalDate);
 }  //Expected out put Final Date is 2016-02-24 20:05:07
```