# Coldfusion calculate accountExpires

Tags: datetime, coldfusion, active-directory

I'm trying to get all the accounts that have EXPIRED using accountExpires attribute in Active Directory.

As the attribute type is Int8 (64-bit integer) and coldfusion does not support such long integer, I am having a hard time getting this to work.

Is there a function or some sort that I can use to acheive the above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A 64 bit integer in Java is a [java.lang.Long](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html). Longs are implicitly [converted to Integers](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Java_8.html) in ColdFusion.

`accountExpires` is a [windows file time structure](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/188768) representing the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199478/java-display-windows-utc-time/5199640#5199640) shows how we can get a windows file time to date:

> ```
> long diff1601to1970 = 315532800 * 1000000000; // <-- diff in nanoseconds(1/1/1601 to 1/1/1970)
> long currentFrom1970 =  System.currentTimeMillis() * 1000000;
> long currentFrom1601 = diff1601to1970 + currentFrom1970;
> ```

Which allows us to do the following in ColdFusion:

```
accountExpiresFileTime = 129407978957060010;
date = createObject("java", "java.util.Date").init(
    (accountExpiresFileTime-116444736000000000)/10000
);
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the reply. I've tried `<cfset objJava = createObject("java","java.util.Date")>` `<cfset dateJava = objJava.init((129407978957060010-116444736000000000)/10000)>` I get the error : INIT Can not find the appropiate constructor to call, Please use javacast to specify parameter type. but when I try: `<cfset dateJava = objJava.init('1/1/2011')>` it is OK. Any idea? :(

Comment: Works for me. CF 9,0,1,274733. Sometimes coldfusion can get confused with overloaded java methods. So try wrapping your argument in a java cast `<cfset dateJava = objJava.init(javacast("long", (129407978957060010-116444736000000000)/10000))>`

Comment: I'm running CF5 at the moment. I'm pretty sure I've tried javacast before but I'll double check on Monday

Comment: Ok,for some reason, the CFLDAP is failing to retrieve accountExpires attribute. Same for all other Int8 attributes. Any idea how to get this to work? :(

Comment: I don't I am afraid - however that is a different question so I suggest you post it as a separate question. But once you have found out why cfldap isn't working - at least you now know how to use the windows file time in CF!