# Groovy retrieve file version property (Windows)

Tags: windows, file, properties, groovy, version

Could you please help me to retrieve file version property from Groovy script (in Windows platform)?

I mean the Version property available in Windows (7) in **Details** tab of file **Properties** window opened by right-click on file name.

I found to do it with [WSH](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176615.aspx) only.

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828314/getting-file-attributes-in-java

Comment: @moskiteau in that post describes way to retrieve "simple" propeties. I found a lot of such solutions. But file version is "difficult" property to retrieve. I will try and describe Scriptom way. But it looks too heavy for my test deployment script.

Answer (score 0):

First I tried to find a solution with and "More New I/O APIs for the Java™ Platform" (NIO.2) but didn't succeed. When I looked closer at your WSH-example I realized it is COM scripting.

So there are 2 possiblities to solve this:

- [Com4j](https://com4j.java.net/)
- [Java Native Access (JNA)](https://github.com/twall/jna)

An example for accessing Word from Java can be found [here](https://github.com/wolftobias/jna/blob/ef19ab440bef75bca52429e571e93b34c3df426f/contrib/msoffice/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/office/MSWord.java).

**Update**
I tried to solve your problem, but run into an exception within the Namespace-function:

```
@Grab(group='net.java.dev.jna', module='platform', version='3.5.2')

import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.COM.COMException
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.COM.COMObject
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.OleAuto;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Variant;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Variant.VARIANT;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WTypes.BSTR;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.HRESULT;

public class Shell extends COMObject {

    public Shell() throws COMException {
        super("Shell.Application", false);
    }

    public HRESULT Namespace(String dir) throws COMException
    {
        def bstrDir = OleAuto.INSTANCE.SysAllocString(dir)
        def varDir = new VARIANT(bstrDir)
        def result = new VARIANT.ByReference()
        HRESULT hr = oleMethod(OleAuto.DISPATCH_METHOD, result, this.iDispatch, "Namespace", varDir);
    }
}

def shell = new Shell()
shell.Namespace("C:\\Temp")
```