# Setting file creation timestamp in Java

Tags: java, file, date, jfilechooser

I know setting the creation timestamp doesn't exist in Java because Linux doesn't have it, but is there a way to set a file's (Windows) creation timestamp in Java?  I have a basic modification timestamp editor I made right here.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class chdt{
    static File file;
    static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Input a file to change");
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{

            final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
            fc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);

            //BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            //System.out.println("Enter file name with extension:");
            //String str = bf.readLine();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Input a file to change.");
            frame.setSize(300, 200);

            frame.setVisible(true);

            int retVal = fc.showOpenDialog(frame);
            if (retVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                frame.setVisible(false);
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "3RR0RZ!  You didn't input a file.");
                System.exit(0);
            }

            //System.out.println("Enter last modified date in 'dd-mm-yyyy-hh-mm-ss' format:");
            //String strDate = bf.readLine();
            String strDate = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter last modified date in 'dd-mm-yyyy-hh-mm-ss' format:");

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss");
            Date date = sdf.parse(strDate);

            if (file.exists()){
                file.setLastModified(date.getTime());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Modification is successful!");
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File does not exist!  Did you accidentally it or what?");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "3RR0RZ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have the following options:

1. Find a tool that does this and is callable from the command line. Then you can interact with it from your java code.
2. The following link from MSDN [File Times](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) shows how any tool would be doing it - especially note the functions `GetFileTime` and `SetFileTime`.

And here I guess you will be lucky :)  Searching for those functions on Google I found a post here on SO. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3350512/2742805) (not the accepted one) to [How to Discover a File's Creation Time with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586/how-to-discover-a-files-creation-time-with-java) seems to do exactly what you want using JNA and the methods above. And if it does, then please upvote that answer one more time :)

Please don't mind the title it has a method to set the creation time too. I hope you will manage to get it working.

Answer (score 42):

Here is how you do it in Java 7 with the nio framework:

```
public void setFileCreationDate(String filePath, Date creationDate) throws IOException{

    BasicFileAttributeView attributes = Files.getFileAttributeView(Paths.get(filePath), BasicFileAttributeView.class);
    FileTime time = FileTime.fromMillis(creationDate.getTime());
    attributes.setTimes(time, time, time);

}
```

the `BasicFileAttributeView.setTimes(FileTime, FileTime, FileTime)` method arguments set the last modified time, last accessed time, and creation time respectively.

Comment: Hmm does this allow setting the last modified time <  (earlier)  than the creation time ?
???

Comment: set creation time not work on macOS, see https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8151430

Answer (score 24):

Starting from **Java 7**, you can use [**`java.nio.file.Files.setAttribute`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#setAttribute-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-java.nio.file.LinkOption...-) and the `creationTime` attribute:

```
Path p = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\first.last\\test.txt");
try {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(2010, Calendar.MARCH, 20);
    Files.setAttribute(p, "creationTime", FileTime.fromMillis(c.getTimeInMillis()));
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Cannot change the creation time. " + e);
}
```

Other attributes can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributeView.html):

> ```
> Name                  Type
> -------------------------------
> "lastModifiedTime"    FileTime
> "lastAccessTime"      FileTime
> "creationTime"        FileTime
> "size"                Long
> "isRegularFile"       Boolean
> "isDirectory"         Boolean
> "isSymbolicLink"      Boolean
> "isOther"             Boolean
> "fileKey"             Object
> ```

Comment: Unfortunately, setting the creation time fails silently on some Unixes (e.g. OS X, even though it *should* be supported on HFS). If you want to be sure that it was actually set, read after you wrote and check!

Comment: For me it failed silently on Linux with ext3 and ext4, because these FS just do not support creationDates. Reading the creationDate in Java will return the lastModifiedDate!

Comment: Does not work with Linux.

Answer (score -4):

You should search for java.nio if you are using jdk >= 1.7

You can also try this (worked well for me on Macos Mavericks and get me two different timestamps):

```
file.setLastModified(created.getTime()); //Older Timestamp
file.setLastModified(updated.getTime()); //Newer Timestamp
```

Comment: How does this set the file creation time?