# Android Image file write data while preserving file creation date

Tags: android, metadata, fileoutputstream, android-file

In my application I am editing .jpg exif metadata. After adding metadata I firstly  save outputstream as temp file, then delete original file and then rename temp file to original name.

But this way as new file is created the file creation date gets changed. So what can I do so that the outputstream modifies the original file, keeping file creation date intact.

Thanks

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but the second reply to this post seems to be doing exactly what you need...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198184/setting-file-creation-timestamp-in-javahttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198184/setting-file-creation-timestamp-in-java

Comment: The comment above (from @Dan in 2016) contains a malformed link. This should be the correct link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198184/setting-file-creation-timestamp-in-java