# "last accessed" vs "last modified" file date in java (windows)

Tags: java, windows, last-modified

I have a set of files on my windows directory which are copied from elsewhere.
On checking the properties of one of the files (right click -> Properties), it shows:

Created: Today, February 11, 2013, 2:51:56 PM

Modified: Tuesday, January 01, 2013, 8:30:04 AM

Accessed: Today, February 11, 2013, 2:51:56 PM

The "Created" and "Accessed" fields basically show the time that the file was actually copied to the new directory, while the "Modified" field shows the modified date of the original file.

In Java on using `file.lastModified()` what I get back is the "Accessed" (or "Created") timestamp.
Is there a way to get the "Modified" value of the original file?

Answer (score 3):

Along with utilising "external" library (like mentioned JavaXT) in Java 7 you can also use new file API (check out this [Java 7 nio.2 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html)).

```
File attribFile = new File("/tmp/file.txt");
Path attribPath = attribFile.toPath();
BasicFileAttributeView basicView =
    attribPath.getFileAttributeView(BasicFileAttributeView.class);
BasicFileAttributes basicAttribs = basicView.readAttributes();

System.out.println("Created: " + basicAttribs.creationTime());
System.out.println("Accessed: " + basicAttribs.lastAccessTime());
System.out.println("Modified: " + basicAttribs.lastModifiedTime());
```

Check out [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-nio2-2/) for extra samples.

Comment: Thanks, sounds interesting that Java 7 has this new feature, but will try out Java 7 sometime later. Need to get this working on Java 6 for a project right now :). JavaXT library mentioned above hasn't helped much.

Answer (score 2):

You could add [this JavaXT library](http://www.javaxt.com), and then you'll be able to do something like this:

```
javaxt.io.File file = new javaxt.io.File("/tmp/file.txt");
System.out.println("Created: " + file.getCreationTime());
System.out.println("Accessed: " + file.getLastAccessTime());
System.out.println("Modified: " + file.getLastModifiedTime());
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But this doesn't solve the problem. For the same file, output of the sysout statements above is: 
Created: Mon Feb 11 14:50:08 IST 2013 
Accessed: Mon Feb 11 16:05:16 IST 2013 
Modified: Mon Feb 11 14:52:09 IST 2013 
 
While from the windows properties menu, it shows: 
Created: Today, February 11, 2013, 2:50:09 PM 
Modified: Monday, November 19, 2012, 10:30:23 PM 
Accessed: Today, February 11, 2013, 4:04:45 PM

Comment: On Windows, the javaxt-core library returns a "last modified" date directly from the Windows API so it *should* be correct (i.e. it calls the GetFileAttributesExW function and parses the WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA). Does anyone know of a different Windows API that can be used to retrieve the original modification/creation date of a copied file?

Comment: @tajji I ran a simple test using the code mjuarez posted against a file created in 2011. Here's the stdout from javaxt:
Created: Thu Jan 19 09:25:08 EST 2012
Accessed: Thu Jan 19 09:25:08 EST 2012
Modified: Mon Nov 28 09:15:34 EST 2011
I copied the file using Windows file explorer and got the following stdout for the new file.
Created: Mon Feb 11 22:26:26 EST 2013
Accessed: Mon Feb 11 22:26:26 EST 2013
Modified: Mon Nov 28 09:15:34 EST 2011
The modified date remains unchanged. Also, the dates in the stdout match the dates listed in the Windows property dialog. How were your files copied?

Answer (score 0):

As far as JavaXT, and Java 7 didn't work for you, you cat try some more exotic approaches, if you are ready to stick with Windows platform only. As far as, file creation attribute is not exists on most *nix file systems, so it's not seems like big restriction.

1). pasre output of

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c dir c:\\logfile.log /tc");
```

working example [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-the-file-creation-date-in-java/)

2). Try another "external" library. E.g. [FileTimes](http://www.download3k.com/Web-Authoring/Java-JavaScript-Editors/Download-Canadian-Mind-Products-FileTimes.html)

3). You can utilize JNA to get time calling windows API functions directly. BTW, when I tried to found code example with JNA and file attributes functions, I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586/how-to-discover-a-files-creation-time-with-java), so your question seems to be a duplicate :-)